# Date.getDay function returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek

I've read that https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date. And the index is that Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on. I want to get the day of the week.

But when I try

```
const date = new Date(2018, 11, 9, 10, 33, 30)
date.getDay()
```

The date is friday, which should have index 5, but `getDay` returns 0. This happens in Chrome console and in my React Native apps.

**Update**: Look at the answers. I was about to specify November 9, 2018. But JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. So I should use index 10 for November.

Comment: `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hour [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);` note the `monthIndex` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The months start with 0 (January) and end with 11 (December). With `new Date(2018, 11, 9, 10, 33, 30)` you are one month off.

```
new Date(2018, 10, 9, 10, 33, 30)
```

This is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try checking that date...

```
new Date(2018, 11, 9, 10, 33, 30)
> Sun Dec 09 2018 10:33:30
```

Looks like it's December 9th 2018, [which will be a Sunday](https://www.wincalendar.com/Calendar/Date/December-9-2018) :)